# Update-Database command is missing in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, aspnetboilerplate

- Downloaded .NET Core template v3.4.0
- From VS2017 Package Manager Console, I tried to autocomplete `Update-Database` command but this command does not exist!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtCcg.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For EF Core, you can use [`dotnet ef database update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update) in Command Prompt.

Run that in the **EntityFrameworkCore** folder in Command Prompt, not the VS command window.

Comment: now i downloaded the template version 3.4.1 and the Update-Database command is present, have you added  theMicrosoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools respect to the older version?

Comment: It was [included since v3.0.0](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/commit/96e25499cc671457280f75462a13f8534f1506bc#diff-323ed6c44601352fb2ba3b4fc2d364a9). Perhaps a package restore (by building) was needed.

Answer (score 10):

Did you install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package?

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Update-Database
```

Answer (score 0):

The Above mentioned reasons are valid, But I have also faced this issue sometimes.I have found one workaround for this.

- Open new visual studio instance.
- Open Package Manager Console, let it load.
- Open Project or Solution in the same instance.
- Run Update-DataBase in Package Manager Console.